# Запись даты в блокнот

Tags: python

Нужно сделать так, чтобы скрипт записывал дату, но выдаёт такую ошибку:

> ```
> file.write(datetime.day)
> ```

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not getset_descriptor

```
import random
from datetime import datetime

norm_words = ["Хорошо", "хорошо" "Нормально", "нормально", "Прикольно", "прикольно", "Классно", "класно"]
norm_otvet = ["☆Это отлично! Я рада за вас", "☆Отличненько! У меня тоже всё хорошо", "☆Окей, это хорошо", "☆Поздравляю.", "☆Отлично, у меня тоже всё хорошо", "☆Молодец, а мне вот грустно("]





text = ''
while text != "stop":
    start = input("")

    if start in norm_words:
        print(random.choice(norm_otvet))
        with open("norm.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(datetime.day)
    else:
        print("Что?")
```

Comment: может, `datetime.now().day`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
from datetime import datetime

norm_words = ["Хорошо", "хорошо" "Нормально", "нормально", "Прикольно", "прикольно", "Классно", "класно"]
norm_otvet = ["☆Это отлично! Я рада за вас", "☆Отличненько! У меня тоже всё хорошо", "☆Окей, это хорошо", "☆Поздравляю.", "☆Отлично, у меня тоже всё хорошо", "☆Молодец, а мне вот грустно("]





text = ''
while text != "stop":
    start = input("")
    now = datetime.now() # current date and time 
    day = now.strftime("%d") # current day as string
    if start in norm_words:
        print(random.choice(norm_otvet))
        with open("norm.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(day)
    else:
        print("Что?")
```